# C# Serial Data- Losing data after formatting received data string

Tags: c#, formatting, serial-port

My project is a Customer Display that connects to a restaurant POS (pc based cash register) via serial connection.  I am using C#, Visual Studio 2010.

As the cashier takes the customer's order and enters the items into the POS system, the POS sends string of formatted text via the serial port. I need to take that text and parse it to remove some of the unwanted characters, format it and display it on the screen.

Most of the time, everything works as shown in the first image (note I have the raw unformatted data on the right for reference).  each it is added to the list box, and the tax and total update after each new item is added or removed (if an order correction is made).

PROBLEM: When the POS sends several items quickly something is falling apart and not all of the text is being handled/formatted/placed on screen properly. as show in the second image.

You can see where several of the items 'slipped' through and are showing the items codes.

When I **do not** format the incoming string in any way (in testing), all of the data seems to make it to the screen exactly as it comes in.  So it seems to me that the *handling* of the string is causing the problem and the serial data keeps coming in and some gets dropped.  I've tried every handshaking option available.

first code is what I am now using, the second is a sample of what I used when I built a separate event handler.  both approaches exhibit same problem.

CODE:

```
private void OnDataReceived(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RxString = (myPortController.Read());

        RxString = RxString.TrimStart(new char[] { (char)02 }); // trim the Char02 so I can test for the 'Clear Screen' signal
        if (RxString == "")
        {
        }
        else RxString = RxString.Remove(RxString.Length - 1, 1); // Trim the end of line ascii character (dont need it for list box)

        if (RxString.StartsWith("C"))  // this is the 'Clear Screen' signal.  ClearAll is a simple func. to remove text from all controls
        {                              // to clear the screen after each order.
            ClearAll();

        }
        else  // Next sections display the text on screen, testing for Tax, Total or if not, then its a regular Menu Item

            if (RxString.Contains("Tax"))
            {
                labelTax.Text = RxString.Remove(0, 5);
            }
            else
                if (RxString.Contains("Total"))
                {
                    labelTotal.Text = RxString.Remove(0, 5);
                }

                else

                    if (RxString == "")
                        RxString = "";  // just do nothing with an empty string (dont know better way of ignoring that)

                    else
                    {
                        listOrderItems.Items.Add((RxString.Remove(0, 5)));  // Add the main menu items to the Listbox
                    }

     }
```

METHOD USING A SEPARATE EVENT HANDLE, BUT GOT SAME RESULTS:

```
  private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }
```

Comment: Your post is much too long and contains lots of detail that is not relevant to the issue you are asking about. You are much more likely to get an answer if you trim it down to the bare essentials (are COM details really relevant to what you are asking?).

Comment: Don't know how are you getting the RxString internally ,but maybe you should try splitting it by an EOL char .

Comment: I did my best to trim it down.

Comment: user1062142, http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of information there to grok and I'm not entirely sure you've given us enough to help solve this particular problem.  So instead of an explicit solution, I'm going to propose a way to solve this on your own (and a way to give the SO Community better questions).

Explore test-driven development and build your `OnDataReceived` event handler with components you've fully tested.  The core part of the handler is text processing and you could easily do with another class.  It appears that you're taking once-working code as gospel (and possibly some *coding by coincidence*).

Take some simple acquired text string and build classes that parse them and return the appropriate data.  From there, build more complex test cases with larger strings, cancelled items, etc.  Once you're happy with your tests, then do some testing with hardware and see how it works.  If it fails, you have more test cases to add.

Then... lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: For what it's worth, I made the same mistake when I doing similar development.  You can be quite successful without test-driven development but when you start TDD, you quickly realize how blind you really were.

Comment: Oded- sorry you feel that way. I work for a software company (in sales not programming) and I've learned to never assume anyone knows what im thinking.  I certainly believe the details of how the data is incoming is important.  I read several hundred threads on this site and very often people ask for more details.  I want a solution quickly and I didn't want to have to keep checking back to provide more info. And your post did nothing to assist me in any way.